# Unwanted white section appears on top of website

Tags: html, css

As the title says, there's a portion of white space on my website when changing pages. The index page has no issues, but when going to "Work" or "Contact" page, a white empty space appears.

To demonstrate, please head over to [my website](http://www.pourziaei.com/). Then resize your browser, till the responsive breakpoint (or just use your phone), then using the menu, change to either the "Work" page, or "Contact" page.
I would have solved this issue by now, but the problem persists because I could not debug, use console, or diagnose in any way where the issue arises from.
If you do, please state how you diagnosed it.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit #1:** After a comment pointed out that it could be a JS issue, I looked into my JS code and the only thing I can come up with is that the following lines of code causes the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function setHeightLContainer() {
windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
$('#lContainer').css('min-height', windowHeight);
};
setHeightLContainer();

$(window).resize(function() {
setHeightLContainer();
});
});
```

However, after removing the following code (and anything alike), the issue still persisted.

**Edit #2:** The following is the HTML and JS for Work page.

JS:

```
$(".navSide").on("click",".workButton",(function(){
if (!$(".workButton").hasClass("active")) {
$(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
$("#desTitle").load("work.html #desTitle", function(response,status,xhr) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
  $("#warning").fadeIn("fast");
}});
$("#rContent").animate({width:'toggle'},400, function() {$("#rContent").load("work.html #rContent > *", function(response,status,xhr) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
  $("#warning").fadeIn("fast");
}})});
$("#rContent").animate({width:'toggle'},4500);
$("#lContent").fadeOut(400,function(){
  $("#lContent").load("work.html #lContent > *", function(response,status,xhr) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
  $("#warning").fadeIn("fast");
}});
});
$("#lContent").fadeIn(4500, function(){});
}
}));
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="lContainer">
        <div id="lContent">
            <h1 class="infoHead infoPos" id="lContentWorkHeader">Work</h1>
            <p class="lead shortDes infoPos">Please feel free to take a look at the work I have done so far</p>
            <p class="shortDes infoPos" id="lContentWork">The content on the white portion will always be updated when I've had the opportunity to do more projects. I'm always welcoming new projects as I have no doubt in my abilities.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**(Fix) Edit #3:** A comment from Andy pointed out that the issue might be from a CSS styling. An ID with the `margin-top:30%` caused half of the white screen, and I now have a lead on how to find the rest.
I apologize for my initial post being incomplete, I just had no diagnostics to present.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a JS issue to me.

Comment: But you see, I don't know what part of the code is the issue. If I did I wouldn't just show the demonstration, and at least I would have attempted to fix it myself. Once the issue is resolved, I'll be sure to update this post with the code that caused the problem, so others can benefit from it, is that okay?

Comment: @PraveenKumar JS console doesn't state any issues though.

Comment: @msamprz I am not saying there's an error. I said the issue is caused by wrong JavaScript calculation of the height or something.

Comment: Can you post the HTML and JS code for the "Work" Page

Comment: @DavidYue Hi David, I updated the post, with the code you asked for.

Comment: Hi msamprz,

IE or Chrome offer excellent tools for finding CSS glitches or issues like this.

in your main.css
you have ContentWorkHeader set to margin-top:40%

just right click above the white space on your web page and select view element and you will see all styles applied to the section. 

Remove the Margin and your title will appear at the top of the page as your require.

Try using the tool the same way I have to find the CSS for the second page rule.

Comment: Sorry about cramped answer above I posted as an answer but the question was closed :( Anyhow you can fix both your Work and Contact page quite easily now.

Comment: @AndyDonegan Hi Andy, thank you for your helpful reply, I checked it, and you're right, it reduced the white space, but it's not gone. But now I have a lead and can probably solve the problem from there. Because now I know that the problem is with a CSS styling of margin usage. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem at all, hopefully it will get you pointed in the right direction, You will always have a space above it as you have an empty div sat above the Header section. This will lead to the header dropping at least a row. Try deleting the DIV id="newsbar" and you should have use of the maximum amount of space.

Comment: @AndyDonegan that has been set to `display:none;`, so I doubt that's quite it. But I still did delete it, and it didn't make a difference. And since I wasn't exactly able to view element for the white space (Chrome just refers me to the body which doesn't help), I think I'll just have to go through whichever styling that has a margin and see what's causing the last segment of white space.

Comment: @msamprz I missed that sorry, just checked through there is some complex CSS going on, hard to answer here in comments : the keythings changing the header position and you will need to amend for all display widths. .infoHead ( margin-top:0%;} and .infoPos {top:0%} infohead is currently 18% and infopos is currently -6% they are designed this way to keep your display  styling, I would not recommend changing them but they do get rid of the last white space for you.

Comment: Be aware on small screen sizes they are in place to help content and responsive layout, I can see some issues already arising on your site for small screen views so please be aware of the minefield you are entering by amending the layout. Good luck.

Comment: @AndyDonegan First I'd like to thank you Andy, as you're being more than helpful and I'm very grateful. And I'd like to say that I managed to get the white area reduced down to 5% of the screen height, but I can't find any other properties that affects it at that value. If you are going to look at it, please be sure your browser requests a new download of the main.css file and doesn't load it from cache.

Comment: @msamprz I have cleared cache etc but can not see any changes on your main.css. probably has not populated across the web.

Comment: @AndyDonegan Hi Andy, The last 5% is just simply not being removed, I also updated the css again, you might be able to redownload the changes now.

Comment: @msamprz I have just tried again and the site still has not changed at all for me. I am leaving the office for the day now going coaching. I will take a look in the morning to see if it has updated. p.s. I am deleting browser history completely, I use Chrome for CSS tricks and rules and never keep history so I can work clean.

Comment: @AndyDonegan That's a great tactic, I initially used firefox for personal use and used firefox Dev for developing, and I'd not keep any data left on it, as it would just delete history every time I closed it. I just thought I'd give Chrome a try, and I liked the speed too.
But yeah, thanks a lot again. And sure, take your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it at last.

Could not let this one go.

The white bar at the top when below 767px was actually part of the lContent which size is 100% of content, the Lcontainer seems to be displaying over the top.

The Lcontainer did not have display set, I changed it via Google Chrome attributes to display: inline-block;

No more White Space :)

Change your code to the following to test :

```
<div id="lContainer" style="min-height: 993px;/* position: fixed; */display: inline-block;">
```

Google Chrome to the rescue being able to identify and play with elements whilst seeing results, really does make it an excellent tool.

There are other options you can try but this seems to work ok for me try it out.

Comment: Andy you genius. Thank you, I owe you one. Just message me whenever.

Comment: @msamprz One of those things mate, just could not let it go, sorry at beginning with the short amount of detail I looked at the wrong area. Glad you are all sorted mate :)